# Different Types of Data Getting Stored in Firebase Even though Data is Same

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Authentication

```
String number = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetUpProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("Phone_Number", number);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
```

Passing

```
 final String mNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("Phone_Number");
```

Storing

```
  mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mNumber);
addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String name = input_name.getText().toString();
            String email = input_email.getText().toString();
            String status = input_status.getText().toString();
            String quote = input_quote.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("Unique",Uid);
            userMap.put("Name",name);
            userMap.put("Status", "Hey There");
            userMap.put("Image", "Default");
            userMap.put("Thumb_image", "Default");
            userMap.put("Phone_Number", mNumber);
```

Fetching

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            String name = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String rId = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Log.d("TAAAAG", rId);
            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", rId);
            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", name);
```

Next Activity

```
 MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");

rootRef.child("Chats").child(MessageSenderId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(MessageRecieverId)) {

                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("Seen", false);
                chatAddMap.put("Timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId, chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId, chatAddMap);

                rootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError != null) {
                            Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                        }
                        messageArea.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

When registering the +91 is getting added to database... but when i try to fetch it its fetching without the +91... as a result its totally messing the data up. How to i fetch the number including the +91 or remove tht 91 while authentication... if u need to see my code please ask.

91 is the country code so i hope to fetch the country code instead of just removing the country code

http://ibb.co/ngnyLS

Comment: Please post complete code where you are adding and retrieving from database.

Comment: Look to my edited question please

Comment: you have posted incomplete code in your `Storing` part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking your structure you can see that your **users** are getting registered with **"1212121212"** only and same entries are there in ***chat and messages as well***, but its not the case with **"+91 1212121212"**

While creating chat child you are passing `mNumber` which is **"+91 1212121212"**
and while fetching you are requesting `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();` which will be **"1212121212"**

Please maintain consistency while adding and retrieving data, 
Its clearly visible from your database that Users getting registered without "+91" please do change there and or do change your chat child creation key.